Why does using logging in django corrupt log files?
When I was using logging in my django project, I found that after 2-3 requests for an excuse, the log file got corrupted. Why
in settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d] [%(funcName)s] [%(message)s]'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console_handler': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'info_handler': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filename': os.path.join(INFO_LOG_DIR, 'info.log'),
            'when': 'midnight',
            'backupCount': 30,
            'encoding': 'UTF-8',
        },
        'error_handler': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filename': os.path.join(ERROR_LOG_DIR, 'error.log'),
            'when': 'midnight',
            'backupCount': 30,
            'encoding': 'UTF-8',
        },
        'homework': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filename': os.path.join(HOMEWORK_LOG_DIR, 'homework.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 10,
            'backupCount': 100,
            'encoding': 'UTF-8',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'data_analysis': {
            'handlers': ['console_handler', 'info_handler', 'error_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'homework': {
            'handlers': ['homework', 'console_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    },
}

in other py file:
log = logging.getLogger("data_analysis")

But after sending a few requests, the log file looks like this


python version: 3.6.8
django version: 3.2.3
Part of my project uses multithreading, but when I was testing, I commented out the multithreaded code
I want to be able to log properly
First update:
Current situation:
I use uwsgi
After testing, it was found that as long as I changed the logging configuration to :'format': '%(asctime)s %(pathname)-8s %(message)s', will not damage the log file, no matter how many times I request the api, I can open the log file, but as long as the log format length changes, for example :'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(pathname)-8s %(message)s', then an error must occur after three requests
windows is different from mac, My colleague was able to use the 'format':'%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(pathname)s[line:%(lineno)d] [%(funcName)s] %(message)s' format without log corruption yesterday, Then I tested it again this morning. Yesterday's log format cannot be used. If the log format is changed to this format, the log can be used normally. 'format':'%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(pathname)s %(funcName)s %(message)s'
Updated again:
I tried it again on the server and found that the log file was fine, sending requests did not damage the log file, which records all logs, but the problem still existed on my mac.
On my mac, it only works if the log format is less than or equal to 3 variables, for example :'format': '%(asctime)s %(pathname)-8s %(message)s', is it because of my pycharm? I used 2020.3.5

Corrupted how? You're showing us a PyCharm dialog box, not the contents of the file.

@AKX This file cannot be opened only in pycharm and the server, and can be opened normally in other text editors

So you can open the file with any texteditor? And the file contains the log messages as you expect? Do you use Windows, OS X or Linux?

@OcasoProtal  In mac os and windows, I can use another text editor to open the log file, and after the log file is corrupted, the log message of the request I continue to send is also recorded in the file. In linux, you can use vi or vim to open log files, but only the logs of the first request are recorded, and subsequent requests are not recorded

What does happen when you end the execution of your django project? Do you see the full logs then on any OS? What happens when you use tail?

@OcasoProtal When I use tail, I can only see the log of the first request, not the rest

Well, are you e.g. using a multi-process server? Those processes will certainly trample upon each others' log-writing endeavors.

@AKX I commented out multiprocess multithreading when testing

That doesn't answer my question. Which server are you running this under? gunicorn? uwsgi? Django runserver? Something else?

@AKX I use uwsgi

If the file opens in other editors this is really a PyCharm problem. This support post of on their site might be relevant: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006884619-log-file-keeps-not-being-recognized-then-won-t-open

"but only the logs of the first request are recorded, and subsequent requests are not recorded" did you stop the server before opening the file? There's a chance that the logs are being buffered and you might not be getting live output.

@Rain And are you using e.g. multiple workers and/or multiple threads in your uwsgi configuration? Because logging isn't aware of that sort of thing, and you can just manually try opening the same file twice in w+ or a+ mode in two different processes and try to write to them and see if you get uncorrupted output.

@AbdulAzizBarkat PyCharm is a red herring here. It just can't detect the .log files to smell like text anymore since they're clobbered by writes from multiple processes or threads.

@AKX I'd say PyCharm is very relevant, as they mention the file opens fine in other editors.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Really hard to tell without knowing what the file actually contains (e.g. from an xxd output). For instance, if it's just the first log line followed by a couple of kilobytes of \x00 or something, I imagine PyCharm would sniff it as non-text.

@AKX Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to update the version of pycharm, which is probably the reason of pycharm, because I did not encounter such a situation in the new version of pycharm

@AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to update the version of pycharm, which is probably the reason of pycharm, because I did not encounter such a situation in the new version of pycharm

@AbdulAzizBarkat https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006884619-log-file-keeps-not-being-recognized-then-won-t-open I have also tried the method in this link, and it does not work

@Rain don't add the answer to the question instead post it as an answer.

@AbdulAzizBarkat. I have a new problem, can you help me look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493749/why-doesnt-the-django-program-keep-an-up-to-date-log-but-uwsgi-does

After many attempts, I found that updating pycharm to a new version can solve the above problem, and I updated pycharm to the latest version 2024.1.1 to solve the problem

This does not solve the actual problem you will end up having: multiple uwsgi worker processes/threads clobbering each others' log writes.

@AKX Are there any good solutions to the problem you mentioned?

Naming your logfiles to include the PID of the process would be the easiest...

@AKX What you mean is to write a log file for each process, named after the pid, for example: info_123.log, info_456.log

Yes – then processes won't trample on each others' files.

@AKX I have a new problem, can you help me look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493749/why-doesnt-the-django-program-keep-an-up-to-date-log-but-uwsgi-does
