Why doesn't the django program keep an up-to-date log, but uwsgi does
I used uwsgi to start my project, and then I logged it in my uwsgi configuration, and then I logged it in my django project setup file, but I found out today that my django log only logged this morning from 9:00 to 10:00, and all subsequent logs were missing. But in it's in uwsgi log file, Why?
my uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
socket=/root/ex/xjs/script/uwsgi.sock
master=true
chdir=/root/exam_new/xjy_data_analysis/
wsgi-file=/root/ex/xjs/xjs/wsgi.py
home = /root/anaconda3/envs/xjs
static-map = /static=/root/exam_new/xjy_data_analysis/static
processes=6
worker=6
threads=2
max-requests=5000
thunder-lock=true
enable-threads=true
pidfile=/root/exam_new/xjy_data_analysis/script/uwsgi.pid
vacuum = true
auto-procname = true
procname-prefix-spaced = xjy-data-new-analysis
post-buffering=65536
touch-reload = /root/exam_new/xjy_data_analysis/examApp
daemonize = /root/exam_new/xjy_data_analysis/script/uWSGI.log
harakiri=3600

http-timeout=3600
socket-timeout=3600

chmod-socket = 660

buffer-size=220000000

ignore-sigpipe=true
ignore-write-errors=true
disable-write-exception=true

uwsgi_send_timeout 1800;

uwsgi_connect_timeout 1800;

uwsgi_read_timeout 1800;

my django settings.py
INFO_LOG_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dataAnalysisApp/logs/info')
if not os.path.exists(INFO_LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(INFO_LOG_DIR)

ERROR_LOG_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dataAnalysisApp/logs/error')
if not os.path.exists(ERROR_LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(ERROR_LOG_DIR)


HOMEWORK_LOG_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dataAnalysisApp/logs/homework')
if not os.path.exists(HOMEWORK_LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(HOMEWORK_LOG_DIR)


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d] [%(funcName)s] [%(message)s]'
        }
    },
    'filters': {
        'info_filter': {
            '()': MaxLevelFilter,
            'level': logging.WARNING,
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console_handler': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'info_handler': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'class': 'concurrent_log_handler.ConcurrentTimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filename': os.path.join(INFO_LOG_DIR, 'info.log'),
            'when': 'midnight',
            'backupCount': 30,
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
            'filters': ['info_filter'],
        },
        'error_handler': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filename': os.path.join(ERROR_LOG_DIR, 'error.log'),
            'when': 'midnight',
            'backupCount': 30,
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'homework': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filename': os.path.join(HOMEWORK_LOG_DIR, 'homework.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 10,
            'backupCount': 100,
            'encoding': 'UTF-8',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'logs': {
            'handlers': ['console_handler', 'info_handler', 'error_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'homework': {
            'handlers': ['homework', 'console_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    },
}

my django version : 3.2.3
python version: 3.6.13
My guess is that the multiple processes are causing file handle contention issues, so the logs aren't written to django's log files?
I want to know why this happens?

You will have multiple workers writing into the same file, truncating them (and also messing up rotation). I would suggest setting up a log aggregator to log to, e.g. https://grafana.com/oss/loki/
